# How do I appeal the marking of a question as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, editing

My question here: [Is there a way to retrieve/search through old facebook chat messages?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8124/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-search-through-old-facebook-chat-messages-closed) appears to have been erroneously marked as duplicate. The answers in the linked question, do not cover what I was asking for.

How do I go about appealing that?

Comment: I suggest this should be a FAQ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can say something in the comments and also flag the moderator, or you can come post it here like you did.

But I noticed that you agreed with the duplication now, so we need to get this question closed.